# Angular Frontend Docker container doesn't send/receive data from node express backend Docker container

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, nginx, dockerfile

so I am to docker containers...

I have a frontend application written in Angular.

With a proxy.conf.json holding:

```
/api": {
    "target": "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    "secure": false
}
```

I also added in `environment.prod.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  api: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
};
```

Finally my backend written in Node.js (Express).

In my `app.js`:

```
...
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next()
});
...
```

When I build my apps, and add the frontend to Nginx local with the configuration file properly set up, and PM2 running backend my application running smoothly without any issues.

So following guides and documentations I created a container for my frontend.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

and a container for my backend:

```
# Install the app dependencies in a full Node docker image
FROM node:10

WORKDIR "/app"
# Install OS updates 
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get dist-upgrade -y \
 && apt-get clean \
 && echo 'Finished installing dependencies'
# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./
# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install --production
# Copy the dependencies into a Slim Node docker image
FROM node:10-slim

WORKDIR "/app"
# Install OS updates 
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get dist-upgrade -y \
 && apt-get clean \
 && echo 'Finished installing dependencies'
# Install app dependencies
COPY --from=0 /app/node_modules /app/node_modules
COPY . /app
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV PORT 3000
USER node
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

So as you may have guessed when I run both containers on my laptop (right after I finished the docker build) I can access each one of them but when I try to login I have a POST ... 404 error (Not found).

If I run the frontend locally and the backend from the container it works like a charm....

I have googled a lot, and can't seem to find an answer.

Thank you for your time and help,
Cheers.

**Edit**

As requested my Docker run commands:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 myUserName/cis-backend
docker run -d -p 4200:80 myUserName/cis-frontend
```

Comment: Can you add the docker run command. Looks like you might be not linking the containers or not exposing the ports correctly

Comment: @AvinashReddy, thank you for the quick replay. I just edited as per your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

127.0.0.1 within the frontend container refers to itself. Which explains why it is not connecting

Try launching using the following steps

**This will launch the backend container and set the name to cis-backend**

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name cis-backend myUserName/cis-backend
```

**Launch the cis-frontend container & link it to backend container**

```
docker run -d -p 4200:80 --link cis-backend:cis-backend myUserName/cis-frontend

Syntax for link:
--link <container-name>:<alias>

This will add alias in the /etc/hosts file in the container
```

In the API configuration instead of using `127.0.0.1` use the name `alias` (cis-backend) configured for the first(target) container.

Using [links](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) is a legacy feature and Use of [Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) is recommended for multi-container applications.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and update as soon as I have results.

Comment: I tried and unfortunately it didn't help. 
I fixed environment.prod.ts and proxy.conf.json to both have:
"http://cis-backend:3000" I also tried "http://alias:3000"
build my list file. build the docker container. 
and run with docker containers using the commands you provided. 
Same 404 error. 
I will take the time to read both link you provided this evening.

Comment: Take a look at docker-compose

Comment: Can you exec into the cis-front end container and check /etc/hosts file. Also try doing nslookup to cis-backend

Comment: @AvinashReddy, here is my hosts: 
127.0.0.1 localhost

::1 localhost i[6-localhost ip6-loopback

fe00::0 ip6-localnet

ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix

ff02::1 ip6-allnodes

ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

172.17.0.2 cis-backend d95c9438d78a

172.17.0.3 196fadb8e93b

Comment: nslookup cis-backend resulted: ** server can't find cis-backend: NXDOMAIN
Did that on the frontend container

Comment: cis-backend should be name of the first container. Can I verify if the backend container is launched with the correct name??

Comment: Sure @AvinashReddy, how can I allow that? 
When I run docker ps: 
ID: d95c9438d78a        Image: myUserName/cis-backend    Command: "docker-entrypoint.s…"  Created: 4 hours ago         Status: Up 4 hours         Ports:  0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   Names: cis-backend

Comment: Looks like you didn't udate the first container. It is created 4 hrs ago and I posted answer 3hrs ago. Using `docker contianer rm <contianer-id>` remove the backend service and recreate using this command `docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name cis-backend myUserName/cis-backend`

Comment: Same issue, I also did nslookup and still getting server can't find...

Comment: I joined the slack what's your username there?

Answer (score 2):

After many hours of frustration I finally figured it out.
Yes one of my issues was that I never linked my containers, which I did using a simple docker composer file. 
But the main issue was that in none of the guides I read online does it say that I should update the default.conf in the nginx image of the container.

So to the next person who struggles like me here is a simple step by step: 
In your docker.compose name your backend a specific name. In my case I named it backend. I recommend creating a simple docker container for the frontend just so you could exec (docker exec -it containerId bash) into it to get the info necessary otherwise maybe google the default.conf nginx docker image comes with...
If you created a quick frontend container just to get the file its located at:

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Install vim or whatever you wish.. 
Simple code I used:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install vim
```

Navigate and Open the default.conf file and copy paste it somewhere.
Create a Nginx-custom.conf file in the same folder where you created your dockerfile for the frontend. 
Copy the exact same information that you have found in the default.conf
and add the following under location {..}

```
...
location /api/ {
             proxy_pass http://nameOfTheBackendContainer:portTheBackendIsRunninG;
#   Example: proxy_pass http://backend:3000
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
        }
...
```

In the docker file add the following copy command:

```
COPY nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Now in your frontend code (please note its angular), 
if you used **proxy.conf.json** file for your api you will need to change the api url.
In my case it was changed from:

```
"target": "http://localhost:3000",
```

to

```
"target": "http://backend:3000",
```

I hope this helps someone who is new to this and struggling just like I did.

**Please note I am in no means a professional in this... I am actually just learning all of it and trying to get good at it, this might be a very wrong answer but it worked for me and maybe it will be a starting point for someone else as well.**

If anyone needs more help or a better explanation feel free to message me.